# Grafana worldmap with influxdb shows no datapoints

Tags: grafana

I am trying to use the worldmap plugin of grafana with table data as datasource (in my case influxdb) which got supported with the newest version. link

But sadly I am not able to get it working. I use the same query as in the docu of the plugin but no points are shown in my worldmap. Here are the screenshots of my query:

[image: Metrics]

[image: Worldmap]

Comment: supply error you get

Comment: can you post your query? also how your data in influxdb looks alike!

Comment: The screenshots look like you are using an Elasticsearch data source and not InfluxDB?